# Unique in Mongoose does not work for a second field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use Mongodb and Mongoose for my database, but when I use `unique: true` for the second time in same Schema it does not work.

This is my schema:

```
const User = new Schema({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

For `userName` it works fine but for the `email` field it doesn't work at all.

This is my db config:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    });
```

Please see this image for my current db status: [test documents image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrdjM.png)

They have an unique user names but have the same email.

Comment: are you sure that the unique field was added BEFORE the duplicated documents? Please see mongodb/mongoose logs for a failed index creation

Comment: all i had to do was reset mongodb,

Comment: sry for waste your time

Comment: yes, this is the same thing I wrote to you: now the index creation was ok and you can't insert duplicated email.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i reset mongo and fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Mongo and mongoose fails silently if an index can't be created due to existing non unique fields.

Reset your db or remove duplicated docs and restart your app.